# How can i stick my camera to a curve after a certain frames?

Tags: animation, camera

im new to blender so please dont flame me to hard ;)
I have a construct, made of serveral objects, that "explode" (just spread out a bit) in a 20frame long animation. After that animation i want the camera to move in a circle around the objects. I thought that this might work with the camera following a circle over the parenting menu. It works fine, but starts at frame 0 so it moves while the animation takes place.

Is there any option to set the start of the "path following animation"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have parented the Camera to a circle then set a keyframe at 0 and the point where the rotation should start, this will keep it still. Then set the end keyframe and it will rotate from that point. You can use the Dope sheet to easily slide keyframes around.

Comment: This kind of works. Well, i forgot to say that the camera itself also moves in the animation process. So now it starts circling around while it should be steady moving forward. Any fix? :D

Answer (score 1):

Parent the camera to the circle/curve/path. Then open up the Graph Editor* with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. Click on the very steep curve. In the *Left Menu*, click on your path/curve/whatever.

1. Parent the camera to the circle/curve/path.
2. Open the *Graph editor* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>)
3. Click on the curve, that doesnt look like the other ones
4. Click the "Expensian Thingi" for your curve/path/whatever, that should be listed in the very left menu
5. Click on *Evaluation time*
6. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to enable the menu on the right side
7. Go to the modifiers tab
8. On the "y" field, type in your start frame with `a -` in front (Start frame = 80, input to the field = -80)